# Exclude objects having `is_deleted = True` in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a field `is_deleted`. I have defined a custom manager.

Can I make sure I'm always excluding the objects having `is_deleted = True`?

I wonder if I can override `__init__()` or something directly in `models.Manager` instead of excluding in all the functions defined in my custom manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can always override the default object manager to exclude records by default:

```
class DeletedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DeletedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)


class YourModel(models.Model):
    . . .

    objects = DeletedManager()
```